# Modernizr plugin and webpack encore

Tags: symfony4, webpack-encore

Hello Everyone im using webpack encore in a symfony 4 project .

I did install the modernizr plugin with this command : npm install npm-modernizr@2.8.3 and the plugin is added successfully.

And i have a file that is using this Modernizr as a variable so i did required the modernizr plugin as below :

```
var Modernizr = require('npm-modernizr');
Modernizr.addTest('cssscrollbar', function() {

    var bool,

        styles = "#modernizr{overflow: scroll; width: 40px }#" +
            Modernizr._prefixes
                .join("scrollbar{width:0px}"+' #modernizr::')
                .split('#')
                .slice(1)
                .join('#') + "scrollbar{width:0px}";

    Modernizr.testStyles(styles, function(node) {
        bool = 'scrollWidth' in node && node.scrollWidth == 40;
    });

    return bool;

});
```

modernizr.js:36 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined

at modernizr.js:36

at Object../node_modules/npm-modernizr/modernizr.js (modernizr.js:1406)

at Object../assets/js/Back/plugins/css-scrollbars.js (css-scrollbars.js:3)

I guess i have something missed what is it please ?